# Unable to open Library folder via Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to open a folder `"~/Library/Application Support/Mozilla"` in a Mac App using objective-c.

```
NSString *stringContaingPath = @"~/Library/Application Support/Mozilla";
NSURL *folderURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringContaingPath];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL: folderURL];
```

But each time I get the error

[image: Error]

When I go to open it.

Though the folder does exist.

[image]

Is there something special I need to do to open the folder? I'm not trying to write to it, just open it up for the user to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` symbol is only meaningful to the shell.  You will have to expand it to `/Users/username` using [`NSHomeDirectory()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSHomeDirectory); i.e.:

```
NSString *pathName = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Application Support/Mozilla"];
```

However this will only work in a non-sandboxed app.

Comment: Ah thanks! For those following along at home `NSString *stringContaingPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Application Support/Mozilla", NSHomeDirectory()];`

Comment: @Firemarble Yep.  I prefer my version though :)

Comment: Any difference between the two? Or a reason to use yours over mine? @trojanfoe

Comment: Nothing at all, except using `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` is the accepted method of constructing file names.

Comment: Then I will use that! Thanks for you help!